# How to show the vertical list in horizontal alignment

Tags: php, html, css, templates

https://jmri.org.in/jmri/issue/archive is the site. As you can see that the issues are arranged in vertical list. I want to show them in a horizontal list through html/css.

The code here in the template here is

```
<div class="issues_archive">
        {iterate from=issues item=issue}

            <ul>{if $issue->getYear() != $lastYear}
                <h2>{$issue->getYear()|escape} Issues</h2>
                {assign var=lastYear value=$issue->getYear()}<hr>
                {/if}
                                   {include file="frontend/objects/issue_summary.tpl"}
                        </ul>
                        <br><br>    
        {/iterate}

        {if $issues->getPageCount() > 0}
            <div class="cmp_pagination">
                {page_info iterator=$issues}
                {page_links anchor="issues" name="issues" iterator=$issues}
            </div>
        {/if}
    {/if}
</div>
```

.CSS code is

> ul.csv2 {
>       display: -webkit-inline-box;
>       text-align: center; width: auto; position: relative; }

Comment: The issue is not the HTML.  It's the CSS.  You need to post the relevant CSS here, _not post a link to your site_.  (Once your site is fixed / goes down / goes away / changes, this question is useless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

I've noticed you have structural issues:

```
1. remove all the br tags
2. the h2 tag in issueabc, needs to be outside of csv class
```

After that add

```
display: inline-block;
```

to the ul.csv

Since I haven't worked with PHP in years, my syntax will not be correct, but here it is:

```
{iterate from=issues item=issue}
    {if $issue->getYear() != $lastYear}
        <h2>{$issue->getYear()|escape} Issues</h2>
        {assign var=lastYear value=$issue->getYear()}<hr>
    {/if}
    <ul>
       {include file="frontend/objects/issue_summary.tpl"}
    </ul>
{/iterate}
```

Comment: Hi, I would like to request you to give me exact codes. I have been trying since last one week (used flex as well), bu it didnt work. It will take some time, but please help me with this. I am really tired with this. You can also go on site and add your codes in inspect to see if they are working.